# face detection using a webcam

Tags: c#, .net

i am developing a 3d project and would like to include the following feature :

As my webcam is watching my face, if i move to the left or the right the projects camera position moves to the left or the right to create an "look-around-the-corner" effect .

Does anyone know a face detection project in .NET c# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OpenCV for .NET - there is a [wrapper for .NET](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which also comes with a sample application doing face recognition for images - easy to adapt for the camera if you can extract the samples.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with web services? Depending on how often you need to scan for faces during your webcam stream, you could grab a frame, send it to a face detection web service and it would return the coordinates of faces in that frame.

You could use http://detection.myvhost.de/ because its free!

bafta ;)

Comment: i would like to have a local face detection algorithm , but the site you've pointed out is quite interesting. mersi :D and +1